# Proteus error about coff format. (Coding in C to program a PIC microcontroller)

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c

I am trying to make a code to interface a PIC24FJ128GA010 with a 25LC256 EEPROM.

This the following code:

```c
#include <p24FJ128GA010.h>
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include "softwareSPI.h"

#include <libpic30.h>  // Include for delay functions
#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000

#define SCK   LATAbits.LATA0
#define MOSI  LATAbits.LATA1
#define MISO  PORTAbits.RA2   // Reading MISO pin using PORTAbits

//unsigned char writeSPIByte(unsigned char transmit);
//int writeSPIWord(unsigned short int setting);
//int writeSPI24bits(unsigned short long setting);
//int readSPIWord();
//unsigned char readSPIByte();

unsigned char writeSPIByte(unsigned char transmit){
  unsigned char received = 0;
  unsigned char bits = 8;
  unsigned char tmpbit = 0;

  SCK = 0;

  //make the transmission
  unsigned char mask = 0x80;                //Initialize to write and read bit 7
  unsigned char ret = 0;                    //Initialize read byte with 0
  
  do{
    //Clock out current bit onto SPI Out line
    if (transmit & mask)
      MOSI = 1;
    else
      MOSI = 0;
    SCK = 1;            //Set SPI Clock line
    if (MISO)
      ret |= mask;      //Read current bit fromSPI In line
    __delay_us(1);      //Ensure minimum delay of 500nS between SPI Clock high and SPI Clock Low
    SCK = 0;            //Set SPI Clock line
    mask = mask >> 1;   //Shift mask so that next bit is written and read from SPI lines
    __delay_us(1);      //Ensure minimum delay of 1000ns between bits
  }while (mask != 0);
  
  return ret;
}

/*int writeSPIWord(unsigned short int setting)
{
  int data;
  unsigned char b1, b2;
  b1 = writeSPIByte(setting >> 8);
  b2 = writeSPIByte(setting);
  data = b1 << 8 | b2;
  __delay_us(50);
  return data;
}

int writeSPI24bits(unsigned short long setting)
{
  unsigned short long data;
  unsigned char b1, b2, b3;
  b1 = writeSPIByte(setting >> (unsigned short long)16);
  b2 = writeSPIByte(setting >> 8);
  b3 = writeSPIByte(setting);
  data = (unsigned short long)b1 << (unsigned short long)16 | b2 << 8 | b3;
  __delay_us(50);
  return data;
}

int readSPIWord(){
  int data;
  unsigned char b1, b2;
  b1 = writeSPIByte(0x00);
  b2 = writeSPIByte(0x00);
  data = b1 << 8 | b2;
  return data;  
}*/
unsigned char readSPIByte(){
  unsigned char data;
  data = writeSPIByte(0x00);
  return data;
}
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
xc16-gcc.exe -o "./Debug.cof" "main.obj" -g --debug -omf=coff -mcpu=24FJ128GA010 -Xlinker --script="p24FJ128GA010.gld" 
COFF format is not supported, please use ELF
make: *** [Debug.cof] Error 1

Error code 2
```

Even though I changed this in the properties like below:
[image]

Anybody knows why this happening?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the actual error message. It seems as if you pasted the source twice... -- Oh, and while you're at it, please add the content of the output window as text. Generally avoid screenshots of text. (Here it is OK for the options window.)

Answer (score 1):

The shown command lines make it obvious:

Additionally to the **compiler**, you need to set the **linker** option to produce ELF.

Comment: do you have any idea how to set the linker option to produce elf?

Comment: @P-Em Change the "Tool" dropdown from "CC" to "LD"? I don't have Proteus... (Know your tools, it has documentation, for sure.)